# Custom Login not working in Spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are trying to create custom login page. Our configure method is written as below

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.csrf().disable().formLogin();UserDetailsService

        http.csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
    }
```

We are using UserDetailsService class to store user data.

```
@Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

We have created login.jsp under Web-Inf/views folder structure. Now if try to hit login page we are getting error as below in console.

"web.servlet.PageNotFound:1120 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'".

I am new to Spring framework can anyone help me to find where i went wrong.

Below I pasted full SecurityConfig class code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean(name = "authMgr")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.csrf().disable().formLogin();

        http.csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a controller?

Comment: no controller for login. I gave jspViewResolver in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter extended class and now my custom login works

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful for some one. The problem is that I dint say the spring where it should search for jsp file. After providing below method in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class, custom login worked fine.

```
@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        jspViewResolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
        jspViewResolver.setRedirectHttp10Compatible(false);
        jspViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");

        jspViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        jspViewResolver.setOrder(2);

        return jspViewResolver;
    }
```